# Change text "Show"/ "Hide" on Button Click not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show-hide, jquery-events

My desire output is to hide paragraph when user click on a button and the same button will use for hiding paragraph and change a name of the button as well.

As you can see the output in a snippet, When I click on Button then the text of the button is not changed and the paragraph is also not showing.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $("p").hide("slow", function(){
                if($("#myShowHidebtn").prop('value', 'Show'))
                              $('#myShowHidebtn').html('Hide');
                alert("The paragraph is now hidden");
            });
            $("#myShowHidebtn").on("click", function(){
                 if($("#myShowHidebtn").prop('value', 'Hide'))
                              $('#myShowHidebtn').html('Show');
                alert("The paragraph is now hidden");
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button id="myShowHidebtn">Hide</button>
    <p>Paragraph Containt..Paragraph Containt..Paragraph Containt..Paragraph Containt..Paragraph Containt..</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You can see the error in the snippet. `Html()` -> `html()`. JS is case sensitive

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I did it! Still not showing me paragraph texts.

Comment: you have to check the button id or value and based on it you have to hide/show the paragraph

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly `Html()` is incorrect. The method name is `html()`.

The issue with your logic is that you're adding a new `click` handler to the `button` element every time it's clicked. To fix the logic simply call `toggle('slow')` on the `p`, and then update the `text()` of the `button` based on it's current setting, directly in the click handler. You can also use `stop()` to prevent quick successive clicks from filling up the animation queue. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("p").stop(true).toggle("slow");
    $("#myShowHidebtn").text(function(i, t) {
      return t == 'Hide' ? 'Show' : 'Hide';
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="myShowHidebtn">Hide</button>
<p>Paragraph Containt..Paragraph Containt..Paragraph Containt..Paragraph Containt..Paragraph Containt..</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$("#myShowHidebtn").on("click", function() {
  console.log($(this).text() == 'Hide')
  if ($(this).text() == 'Hide') {
    $('#myShowHidebtn').text('Show');
    $("p").hide("slow");
  } else if ($(this).text() == 'Show') {
    $('#myShowHidebtn').text('Hide');
    $("p").show("slow");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="myShowHidebtn">Hide</button>
<p>Paragraph Containt..Paragraph Containt..Paragraph Containt..Paragraph Containt..Paragraph Containt..</p>
```

1. Remove the event handler for button
2. Add the event handler using `ID`
3. Check text if equal hide and show

Answer (score 2):

Your code is a bit to complex and not correct logically.

- The correct function name is `html()` not `Html()`
- You are adding an event handler on to the button in the callback function of the other click event. This will add a new event-listener every time the button is clicked. This should be removed.
- Instead of having to handlers, add your logic in to just one, making sure every time the button is clicked you toggle the text of the button and paragraph to.

This should work quite well:

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  $("p").toggle("slow", function(){
    if ($("p").is(':visible')) {
      $('#myShowHidebtn').html('Hide');
    } else {
      $('#myShowHidebtn').html('Show');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="myShowHidebtn">Hide</button>
<p>Paragraph Containt..Paragraph Containt..Paragraph Containt..Paragraph Containt..Paragraph Containt..</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems that should be corrected in your code:

- In your actual code you are making a big mistake by attaching the
  `click` event handler to your button twice, it will cause an infinite
  loop because you are reattaching the `click` handler in the button
  `click` itself.
- You are using the `value` of the button incorrectly in your `if`
  condition, the following  `$("#myShowHidebtn").prop('value', 'Show')` is not correct, this should be `$("#myShowHidebtn").prop('value') === 'Show'`.
- And another problem is that you are not changing the button `value` so you
  can test upon it, you are changing the `button` html so you just need
  to test over `.html()`.

**Solution:**

I tried to refactor your code and correct all the mistakes, this is what you need:

```
$("#myShowHidebtn").on("click", function() {
  if ($("#myShowHidebtn").html() === 'Hide') {
    $('#myShowHidebtn').html('Show');
    $("p").hide("slow");
  } else {
    $('#myShowHidebtn').html('Hide');
    $("p").show("slow");
  }
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
$("#myShowHidebtn").on("click", function() {
  if ($("#myShowHidebtn").html() === 'Hide') {
    $('#myShowHidebtn').html('Show');
    $("p").hide("slow");
  } else {
    $('#myShowHidebtn').html('Hide');
    $("p").show("slow");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="myShowHidebtn">Hide</button>
<p>Paragraph Containt..Paragraph Containt..Paragraph Containt..Paragraph Containt..Paragraph Containt..</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the property value not doing an if and you are also binding an extra click event on every click.  Try the following (comments in jQuery below)

```js
$("#myShowHidebtn").click(function() {  // bind the click to the button
  var button = $(this);

  if (button.html() == 'Hide') {   // check the html (the button has no value and prop('','') is a setter not a getter
    $("p").hide("slow", function() {  // do your hide
      button.html('Show');
    });
  } else {
    $("p").show("slow", function() {  // do your show
      button.html('Hide');
    });
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="myShowHidebtn">Hide</button>
<p>Paragraph Containt..Paragraph Containt..Paragraph Containt..Paragraph Containt..Paragraph Containt..</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$('#myShowHidebtn').html('Show'); $('#myShowHidebtn').html('Hide');` not `.Html` - JavaScript function names are case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#myShowHidebtn").click(function(){
        $("p").toggle(function(){
           if($("#myShowHidebtn").text() == "Hide"){ 
               $("#myShowHidebtn").text("Show"); }
           else{ $("#myShowHidebtn").text("Hide"); }
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

In this little code snippet I define the default behaviour of the button - `hide`. We then do a simple check on the `p` tag - is it hidden or not? If so, change the function to `show`. We then perform the function on the `p` tag and, based on the name of the function, show the appropriate value in the button.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var func = 'hide',
      $this = $(this),
      $p = $this.next();
    if ($p.is(':hidden')) {
      func = 'show';
    }
    $p[func]('slow', function() {
      $this.html(func == 'hide'?'Show':'Hide');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="myShowHidebtn">Hide</button>
<p>Paragraph Containt..Paragraph Containt..Paragraph Containt..Paragraph Containt..Paragraph Containt..</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rory right, "Html" tag is root of the problem as JS is case sensitive

I've changed code a little bit to looks smarter.

```
var hidden = false;
$("#myShowHidebtn").click(function() {
    if (hidden == false)
  {
    $("p").hide("slow", function() { 
      $("#myShowHidebtn").html("Show");
      alert("The paragraph is now hidden");
      hidden = true;
    });
  }
  else
  {
    $("p").show("slow",  function() {
        $("#myShowHidebtn").html("Hide");
        alert("The paragraph is now shown");
        hidden = false;});
  }
});
```

Working fine, check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/k43jkv1k/5/)

Regards,